# Latex \ref{xxx} gives (??) (using jupyterlab, miktex, pdflatex)

Tags: cross-referencing

I try to compile a pdf in jupyterlab. When it comes to figure references the pdf showes only (??).

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{xxx.png}
   \caption{Caption of image xxx.png.}
   \label{fig1:xxx}
\end{figure}

(\ref{fig1:xxx})
```

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: I'm not sure how to compile twice when compiling from jupyterlab....

Comment: I also noticed that a .synctex.gz file is generated but no .aux file.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about jupyterlab, but if no `.aux` file is generated (or is generated but removed), then you have a problem...  Check if some setting automatically removes the `.aux` file, or if it uses `\nofiles` somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration file called `config.py` in the folder `jupyterlab_latex` that can be used to set configuration options. The file contains the following:

```python
""" JupyterLab LaTex : live LaTeX editing for JupyterLab """

from traitlets import Unicode, CaselessStrEnum, Integer, Bool
from traitlets.config import Configurable

class LatexConfig(Configurable):
    """
    A Configurable that declares the configuration options
    for the LatexHandler.
    """
    latex_command = Unicode('xelatex', config=True,
        help='The LaTeX command to use when compiling ".tex" files.')
    bib_command = Unicode('bibtex', config=True,
        help='The BibTeX command to use when compiling ".tex" files.')
    synctex_command = Unicode('synctex', config=True,
        help='The synctex command to use when syncronizing between .tex and .pdf files.')
    shell_escape = CaselessStrEnum(['restricted', 'allow', 'disallow'],
        default_value='restricted', config=True,
        help='Whether to allow shell escapes '+\
        '(and by extension, arbitrary code execution). '+\
        'Can be "restricted", for restricted shell escapes, '+\
        '"allow", to allow all shell escapes, or "disallow", '+\
        'to disallow all shell escapes')
    run_times = Integer(default_value=1, config=True,
        help='How many times to compile the ".tex" files.')
    cleanup = Bool(default_value=True, config=True,
        help='Whether to clean up ".out/.aux" files or not.')
```

Set `run_times = Integer(default_value=1` to `run_times = Integer(default_value=2` to run LaTeX two times. Save the file and restart Jupyter Lab for the changes to take effect. Then the reference will be shown in the pdf correctly.

Note that you should not have any `.bib` files in the same folder, otherwise JupyterLab LaTeX will try to run Bibtex and fail, instead of running LaTeX two times (unless of course you want to include a bibliography).

Comment: I do wonder why not use `latexmk`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik of course that is another possibility (set `latex_command` to `latexmk -xelatex`), the solution I picked for my answer seemed a bit more explanatory though (ie., explicitly running LaTeX two times).

Comment: Yeah, that's a good approach too. Though what I meant really is why doesn't jupyterlab use `latexmk` (which _works_) instead of making a build tool of its own.

Comment: @Marijn, Thanks, that works! Since you mentioned Bibtex; I certainly will use Bibtex in a later stage. Out from your answer I understand one should avoid .bib file in the same folder. Where should .bib then be located?

Comment: @mati the `.bib` file can and should be placed in the same directory. When you have commands for citing, bibliography style, and the name of the `.bib` file in your code, it will work normally. However, when you don't have such commands, like in the example code in this question, and you do have an unrelated `.bib` file somewhere in the folder, then JupyterLab-LaTeX will be confused and you will get an error and the figure label/ref will not work.